# Two column list with images and border - rotate border but not image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have rebuilt the old flash website of a friend. Now I still problems. Here is the example:

On the left side logos are displayed. On mouseover the border should be rotated. But in my case the logo rotates to. In addition the logo is not centered vertically.

So how I can center the images and also ensure that they are not rotated. Is there something possible with CSS or can I recreate the same list again without border which overlaps the other?

Thanks in advance

PS Maybe you can show me improvements for this example. Because I´m not a Expert in HTML/CSS...

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ErJTM/2/

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JS9EX/3/)?

Comment: @Teemu: The problem is, that margin-top: 25px doesn´t work in my case. Because the images are different in height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some points:

To center an element within another element you can do something like this:

```
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px; 
    margin: auto;
}
```

Notice, that the position of an absolute positioned element is related to its [`offsetParent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetParent). Hence you need to  to position at least one element in a parent chain (usually as `relative`).

`transform: rotate()` rotates all elements within the element to which it's used. To tackle this, you need to rotate the elements you don't want to rotate, to opposite direction.

[A heavily simplified demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pGJWb/1/).

Comment: One last question: How I have to set z-index, when the border should be abobe the image?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/pGJWb/4/ . The rotating border disappears under the image. How can I change the code that the border stays above the image.

Comment: @MRae I was about to give up with this, but finally, [there you have it](http://jsfiddle.net/pGJWb/9/) : ). There seems to be a bonus blur effect in FF, other browser (Chrome, IE) don't have it. Btw. the CSS won't work in IE<8. Though those browsers don't have a support for rotation either...

Comment: Now the link isn´t working. I can set it in the new <div> too. But I think that isn´t a good idea.

Comment: Somehow the `div` shadows the link in FF, Chrome and Opera. In IE links are available normally. I'll take a closer look to this later tonight...

Comment: @MRae I'm sorry, I didn't have time to study this last night. If you can accept, that also the `div` is a part of link, you can simply move it into `a` ([a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pGJWb/12/)).

Comment: @MRae _Your_ code maybe is not valid, but _my_ code is. After adding `alt` attribute get "`Congratulations, The uploaded document was successfully checked as HTML5.`" using W3C Validator. Did you notice, that there are some fixes in the HTML compared to your original fiddle. Also a HTML fragment is validated against HTML 4.01, not "HTML5". In HTML4 there are not self-closing tags, and the content of [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) is more limited ([standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)).

Comment: @MRae If you want the snippet to be valid HTML4, change `div`s to `span`s, and remove the `/` from the end of `img` tags. And the `alt` attribute is ofcourse required in any HTML.